# Getting temporary AWS credentials using Java SDK2

Tags: aws-sdk

The AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/prog-services-sts.html) seems still to refer to AWS Java SDK1 with regard to STS / assume role authentication.

If I have:

- AWS Java SDK2 (v.2.5.49)
- role-arn
- external-id

..is there a way to create with those:

- accessKey
- secretKey
- sessionToken

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One should use `StsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider` that does the refreshing of temporary tokens for you.

```
def apply(roleArn: String, externalId: String, expires: FiniteDuration, sessionName: String): StsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider = {
    val durationSecs: Int = expires.toSeconds.toInt

    val stsClient: StsClient = StsClient.builder.build()

    val req: AssumeRoleRequest = AssumeRoleRequest.builder
      .roleArn(roleArn)
      .externalId(externalId)
      .durationSeconds(durationSecs)
      .roleSessionName(sessionName)
      .build()

    StsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider.builder
      .stsClient(stsClient)
      .refreshRequest(req)
      .build()
  }
```

Note that when calling `.resolveCredentials()` the AWS SDK 2 returns an `AwsCredentials` that does not provide the session token. The returned value can just be casted to `AwsSessionCredentials` which provides all the three.

```
val prov: AwsCredentialsProvider = ???
val creds: AwsSessionCredentials = prov.resolveCredentials().asInstanceOf[AwsSessionCredentials]
```